# If frame-rate <= 2, video from images is a black screen

Tags: image, matlab, video, image-processing

I made a video from 40 images using first Matlab and then "A4 video converter" just to compare results. I found something happening that I don't understad and maybe somebody can explain to me.

**When I set frame-rate at 2 frames per second and I play the video I can only see a black screen.**

If I set frame rate more than 2 frames per senconds then I can see the video perfectly.
This happens with both programs, so I guess it is not a bug, but maybe some physics or signal processing issue.

Why is this happening?

Comment: The screen is being updated 60+ times a second anyway, so it isn't a physics issue.  I'd wager it is an issue with that video card's drivers, so it would be worth trying it on a different computer.  If you'd like to test it another way set the fps to 3 and make triplicates of every frame.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why it is happening, but a workaround could be to show each pic twice. This would allow you to play it at 4 frames per second without speeding up the video.